# TypeError: function missing 1 required positional argument: 'path' Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, static, static-libraries

I have a static folder and my main usage is a sub-directory there that is found in 
root/static/images/monkeys

I have a flask app and I have a variable like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
monkeys_folder_path = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'images', 'monkeys')
```

I use it in two functions, one function serves a static image in that folder, this function works:

```
@app.route('/monkey/<address>')
def serve_static(address):
    # this creates an image in /static/images/monkeys
    monkey_generator.create_monkey_from_address(address)
    filename = address + ".png"
    return send_from_directory(monkeys_folder_path,filename)
```

I also have another function that uses this path, this function deletes images after X seconds from the folder

```
def remove_monkey_images(path):
  threading.Timer(5.0, remove_monkey_images).start()
  # this function iterates in a loop over the files in the path and deletes them
  helper_functions.delete_images(path)
```

This function does not work, when I run the server locally I get

```
 File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: remove_monkey_images() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

I call the function like so:

```
remove_monkey_images(path=monkeys_folder_path)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This answer saved my day. It works perfectly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591487/10062300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the `Timer`, you have to pass it the called function's arguments, like this:

```
threading.Timer(5.0, remove_monkey_images, (path,)).start()
```

[*Source*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=lock#threading.Timer)

As for the rest of your code I don't really know if it's consistent, but at least that's the cause of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Python function can have `positional` or `keyword` [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html). Your function definition

```
def remove_monkey_images(path)
```

describe function with one `positional` parameter. This function could be called only with one positional argument like

```
remove_monkey_images(monkeys_folder_path)
```

If you want to use `keyword` argument you needs

```
def remove_monkey_images(path='/some_default_path')
```

In this case you could call function both with

```
remove_monkey_images(monkeys_folder_path)
```

and

```
remove_monkey_images(path=monkeys_folder_path)
```

and

```
remove_monkey_images()
```

In latter case inside function argument `path` will have default value '/some_default_path'.

Comment: This isn't true; positional parameters can be passed in kwarg form too. Both ``remove_monkey_images(monkeys_folder_path)`` and ``remove_monkey_images(path=monkeys_folder_path)`` will work.

Comment: Could you provide function definition for your case?

Comment: Well say you have a function defined as: `def my_function(positional_param): pass`

You could either call it as: `my_function(positional_param="value")`
or `my_function("value")`, both will work.

Answer (score 1):

there is a syntax issue with your problem.

Either do this:

```
remove_monkey_images(monkeys_folder_path)
```

instead of

```
remove_monkey_images(path=monkeys_folder_path)
```

or

Update your function definition as:

```
def remove_monkey_images(path=None):
  threading.Timer(5.0, remove_monkey_images).start()
  # this function iterates in a loop over the files in the path and deletes them
  helper_functions.delete_images(path)
```