# Flask shows TypeError: send_from_directory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

Tags: python, flask

When I deploy my Flask app on Azure, the view raises `TypeError: send_from_directory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'`. This isn't happening when I run locally.

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    uploads = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 18):

Change the final line to `return send_from_directory(uploads, filename)`.

See the Flask docs about [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory). The changelog at the bottom that says "Changed in version 2.0: `path` replaces the `filename` parameter."

If you still want to use named parameters, change `filename=` to `path=`. `send_from_directory(directory=uploads, path=filename)`

Answer (score 3):

```
return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

change to

```
return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, path=filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> In my case I need certificate, it is saved inside  static/pdf/certficates
> folder

```
@app.route('/download/<filename>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def download(filename):
   uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, "static/pdf/folder_name")
   return send_from_directory(directory=uploads,path=filename,as_attachment=True)
```